# Z-index not working with jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

How is it that this works:

```
$("#linechart").css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: "4%",
      left: "2%",
      height: "92%",
      width: "96%"
  });
```

and this breaks all the javascript:

```
$("#linechart").css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: "4%",
      left: "2%",
      height: "92%",
      width: "96%",
      z-index: "5"
  });
```

Comment: for more flexibity, wrap your attributes and their values in quotes to make it work in every browser.

Comment: when you inspect linechart, you don't see the z-index in firebug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to define like this:

```
"z-index": "5"
```

Or uppercase if you don't want to define in quotes:

```
zIndex: "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$("#linechart").css({
      position:'fixed',
      top: "4%",
      left: "2%",
      height: "92%",
      width: "96%",
      'z-index': "5"
});
```

and reason is when we use css in jQuery we have to write like this if the word has space in between words

Answer (score -1):

You can see this:[jQuery Source Code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js),in 204 line.

```
"zIndex": true
```

Comment: Please do copy out the relevant parts and add a short explantion.